# Remove a \r\n in the middle of a list

Tags: excel, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to process an excel file and write the contents out in CSV. The data is not consistent and they \r\n could be in any cell. Because I'm writing out a list of data I can't convert it to a string and use the replace. I believe CSV is writing out a list.

```
   [W6B07I,04114145,"387 ROLF STREET\r\nNEW JERSY",USA,-,45020.200,-,X,Z]
   with xlrd.open_workbook("excel_file.xlsx") as wb:
   sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)  
   with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as f:   
      c = csv.writer(f,delimiter=',')
      for r in range(sh.nrows):
        myval = sh.row_values(r)
        c.writerow(myval)
```

Comment: You can just go through each entry in the list and if it is a string replace what you want: `result = [x.replace('\r\n', '') if isinstance(x, str) else x for x in my_current_row]`

Comment: Not all values are strings, some are floats

Comment: I see you noticed but that is what the `isinstance` if for. It won't change any values other than `strs`. `floats` remain untouched.